# Find the lowest positioned element

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, snapkit

I'm trying to make constraints via [Snapkit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit) in a table view cell but my problem is I need to find out which element has max y position (The lowest one).

I have an UIImageView and next to image view UILabel elements. The label text is dynamic and could be very long or very short. Below these 2 elements, I have another one that should be aligned based on the label height, either taking image view or label.

My question is how to find which element (UIIMageView, UILabel) has a bigger Y position.

To be more clear I attached a draw with simple two cases.[image]

Comment: Whoever put -1 can you please explain what was wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `greaterThanOrEqualTo` constraint on both elements.

In "plain language":

- AnotherElement.top >= ImageView.Bottom (with constant of 12, or however much space you want)
- AnotherElement.top >= Label.Bottom (with constant of 12, or however much space you want)